# How do i setup auto refresh on smart window?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to know how do i setup auto refresh facility on smart window which should get auto refresh whenever new records gets updated in db.

I could setup refresh button on browser and inside that call the program for retrieve. But the concern here is each and every minute new records gets updated to db so that i need to click the button if i want to see on the browser as its having only initial fetched record while opening.

So i am questioning here is that is open edge have the facility of real time update? i.e will window get automatic refresh once new records uploaded to the specific database table.

I am new and don't know how can I write a query for this. Please throw a lamp here to bright. It would be better.

Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: What is the "back end"? A database? An appserver? Something else?

Comment: @ Jensd . Its a database.

Comment: which other processes are updating the data? You basically need to decide between polling based on a timer and an messaging based solution.

Comment: @ Mike - By using process data's are getting upload to the database table. So concern here is when i open the window then its take initial data fetch only..so each and every time need to close and re open window to get the latest updated data. Here must consider about automatic refresh instead close and reopen window

Comment: There's a huge amount of context missing here. Is the screen classic ABL GUI? CHUI? .Net front end? Answers here will affect the answers you receive. Why do you have to close and open the window? Why not have a refresh button? How will the client know data has changed? Please update your question with these details, what you have tried, and why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic, built-in auto refresh capability for OpenEdge.

Your idea of coding a refresh button is a good start.  If you start with that, and get a manual refresh working to your satisfaction you can then focus on automating the button press.

There are a number of ways that you might choose to do that.  The specifics are dependent on your platform and the application framework that you are using.  You mention "smart window" so I am guessing you must be on Windows and using the really old and crusty stuff.

For that environment you probably just want to add a "pstimer" ActiveX. That's not really the modern way of going about things but it might be the best fit for the world that you actually live in.

There are many Progress kbase articles on how to do that.  This might be a good start: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19064

There are probably perfectly good .NET equivalents too.  The key is to first code your "refresh button" so that the critical logic just needs to be triggered from time to time.

Comment: - I just followed the link that you provided and added "pstimer" on smart window. If i do so i could see fill in box values are getting  increases by 1 every two seconds means screen gets refresh right? So how do i understand this? For every 2 seconds the data is retrieve from db? I am sorry if i misunderstood.